# Winter Bash 2022 Millnery

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Winter Bash 2022 is here on History.SE! Post a reply here to model your hats. Let's see what everyone is sporting.

Best looking and/or coolest gets ... er ... the highest score?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Back In My Day]

I don't smoke, but I think I look smashing with a pipe.

[image: Over 9000!]

Goku? After some research, I'm pretty sure the "secret" has something to do with [this rather badly-recieved meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215533/add-a-spikey-hair-badge).

[image: Introverts Unite]

... separately, in your own homes.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Pay no attention to the spiral behind the curtain.